# Android tabbed layout null pointer unless i view the tab first

Tags: android

I have a tabbed layout im working on. On the second tab it maintains a list of items. If i delete an item from another list on the first tab it should add it to the second by calling a static add method. If i do this when the app first starts, it gives me a null pointer exception because the database variable has not been initialized(checked using debugger) in the activity that resides on the second tab (the onCreate method has not been called). HOWEVER, if i start the app, switch to the tab, then switch back to the first tab and delete an item, it works as normal because the onCreate method was then called. So my question is this, how do i make sure my database is instantiated, or the onCreate in my second activity/tab before i call a static method to add to it?

Here is the code to call the static method

```
ShoppingListActivity.addToShoppingList(name, quan);
```

Here is the static method

```
public static void addToShoppingList(String name, int quan)
{   
    shoppingDb.insertFood(name, quan);
}
```

it is the shoppingDb variable that is not being initialized and is returning null because the onCreate has not been called.

Comment: You mention `onCreate` a number of times, but fail to actually add the code for it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a static method, then why not use a static boolean variable in the second tab, which is false when the application starts, and true, when the OnCreate method called. Then you will be able to test the readiness of the activity in addToShoppingList method. 
But for use it you have to store the data that will come before DB initialized.

Like this:

```
class ShopItemData{
    public String name;
    public int quan;
    public ShopItemData(String n, int q){
         name = n;
         quan = q;
    }
}

private static ArrayList<ShopItemData> shopItems = new ArrayList<ShopItemData>();
private static boolean isDBInitialized = false;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ...
     //initialize your database
     isDBInitialized = true;
}

...

public static void addToShoppingList(String name, int quan)
{   
    if (isDBInitialized){
        if (shopItems.size() > 0){
            for(ShopItemData item:shopItems){
                shoppingDb.insertFood(item.name,item.quan);
            }
            shopItems.clear();
        }
        shoppingDb.insertFood(name, quan);
    }else{ 
        shopItems.add(new ShopItemData(name,quan));
    }
}
```

Comment: That will work to test the readiness, but how will i handle cases where it returns false, items still need to be added to the list. Basically what im wondering is, is there a way to force the oncreate method to run when my app is started either before the tab has been viewed or to start the app on that tab

Comment: No, you can`t force onCreate(). "but how will i handle cases where it returns false, items still need to be added to the list." - for that I wrote an ArrayList of ShopItems that saved items before db is initialized. That will work for you, I`m sure.